# java google api spreadsheet: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-8, google-cloud-platform

I set a spreadsheet handler for google-api in java like that:

```
private GoogleCredential getCredentials(InputStream secret) throws GeneralSecurityException,
        IOException, URISyntaxException {
    GoogleCredential credential;

    if ( secret == null ) {
        credential = GoogleCredential
                .getApplicationDefault()
                .createScoped(SheetsScopes.all());
    } else {
        credential = GoogleCredential
                .fromStream(secret)
                .createScoped(SheetsScopes.all());
    }

    return credential;
}
```

and

```
  public static java.util.Set<String> all() {
    java.util.Set<String> set = new java.util.HashSet<String>();
    set.add(DRIVE);
    set.add(DRIVE_FILE);
    set.add(DRIVE_READONLY);
    set.add(SPREADSHEETS);
    set.add(SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);
    return java.util.Collections.unmodifiableSet(set);
  }
```

I try to run this code on appengine (java8) and i get an exception when i try to read from my spreadsheet (my appengine email is a editor for that spreadsheet)

```
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyLogger warn: /
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

how can i debug or fix this?